# Incorrect name on B1/B2 visa application

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens

A friend of mine is a UK citizen and has completed her B1/B2 visa application. The forms she submitted had the correct information, however the email confirmation confirming her application listed her middle name as her first name and does not list her first name.

Will this cause any problems further down the line and who should she contact to put this right?

Comment: https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-errors/error-in-visa-contact-form/

Comment: What stage of the process are you at? You have submitted the DS-160 online, but have you already scheduled the appointment for an interview? Completed the interview?